# ArangoDB offset doesn't work in join

Tags: arangodb

I got next tables: users_categories, users.

users_categories objects contains "users" fields which has keys only, so I make join:

```
FOR c IN users_categories
FILTER c._key == '75a65608-7e9b-4e74-be19-76882209e388'
FOR u IN c.users 
    FOR u2 IN users FILTER u == u2._key 
    LIMIT 0, 100
    RETURN u2
```

Result:

```
[
{
"_key": "5b1b68db-9848-4a0a-81b3-775007f16845",
"_id": "users/5b1b68db-9848-4a0a-81b3-775007f16845",
"_rev": "_VXo9gaC---",
"activated": true,
"blocked": false,
"citizenship": "RU",
"city": "Kalinigrad",
"deleted": false,
"email": "trigger.trigg@yandex.ru",
"lastActivityTime": 1501539830209,
"login": "triggerJK",
"name": "Max",
"passportId": "8736e8e4-9390-44e7-9e21-b17e18b1ebd9",
"phone": "89092132022",
"profileName": "Default profile",
"sex": 1,
"surname": "Max"
},
{
"_key": "0965a0d9-fc91-449f-90f8-9086944b1a86",
"_id": "users/0965a0d9-fc91-449f-90f8-9086944b1a86",
"_rev": "_VWjRYHe---",
"activated": true,
"blocked": false,
"citizenship": "AF",
"deleted": false,
"email": "megamozg4@mail.ru",
"lastActivityTime": 1501247531,
"login": "Megamozg4",
"passportId": "20ab7aad-d356-4437-86b2-6dfa9c4467e0",
"phone": "12312334555",
"profileName": "Default profile",
"sex": 1
}
]
```

If I set LIMIT 1 or LIMIT 0, 1 it returns only first record, as I want to. However, if I set LIMIT 1, N (N can be any) it returns empty array, so offset doesn't work?

What am I doing wrong?

ArangoDB used: 3.1.10

UPD:
somehow, LIMIT 1, N skips not the only first record, but first 2. 
If I have more than 2 records to show, offset works strange. I created issue on github

Answer (score 1):

Two bugs were reported regarding offsets:

https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2928 
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2879

And the fixes for `LIMIT` are included in the versions v3.1.27 and v3.2.1, so please update and test again.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try 3.1.27 as soon as it appears on docker hub